# Chef: How to run a recipe on multiple node at same time

Tags: chef-infra

I am using chef to configure the apache in multiple linux nodes.
I would like apply a apache cookbook recipe in multiple nodes at the same time. 
Is there any way to run a recipe on multiple node at same time?
Please help..

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This is not something Chef directly handles. We provide `knife ssh` as a very simple solution for the most basic cases, so if you’re just getting started, that is probably what you would use.